# Prevent website from going down while deploying new code

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver

I am running an ecommerce website which is getting decent traffic.

Our website is running on following stack:

1. WebApp is built in Java running on Apache Tomcat
2. We are using Nginx as webserver
3. We are running our webserver on an EC2 instance of AWS - which has Ubuntu as Operating System.

We frequently deploy new code of website to include new features and bugfixes. We follow following procedure for doing this:

1. Shutdown apache tomcat
2. Remove ROOT webapp from `webapps` directory
3. Uploaded new `ROOT.war` in `webapps` directory
4. Restart apache tomcat

Now this process leads in shutdown of website for around 20-30 seconds. Which not only results in loss of new customers in that time as they can't access the website but also leads in several issues with current customers who were in checkout to place order.

Is there any way to tackle this problem? By which I could deploy new version of website without 0 downtime and no loss of session data of existing customers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question with many possible answers.

Essentially you need to get rid of the single box setup and create - either manually/via [Cloudformation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html)/something else - 2 or more application servers sitting behind an [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). When deploying a new version, one of the boxes would have its live traffic drained so existing users are being served by another, working instance.

Or you could use [elastic beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) to package the app and let it do all the heavy lifting for you, this is a very AWS way espcially if your application is quite straight forward.

Search the internet for *blue green deployments*.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I have thought about Elastic Load Balancer, but in that case I would be incurring extra cost for another EC2. I am trying to avoid that. I have read about elastic beanstalk, but haven't give it a try yet as I was unsure, whether it will fit into my requirement or not.
Isn't it possible to create a loadbalancer on an EC2 itself, where I will run 2 tomcat's instance on a single EC2

Comment: Yes it is, you could run HA Proxy, nginx, apache or something else - but that is a different question. Also you can tackle the cost by having 2 _smaller_ instances instead of 1 large one: 2 x t2.small costs the same as 1 x t2.medium.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I have heard blue green deployment for the first time. I am looking into all possibilities suggested by you. Just one last question, in your opinion, in my current situation what could be the best solution you could suggest.

Comment: Given the limited information, go with the option removes your one box as a single point of failure, so 2 smaller instances behind ELB. Then you can look into Beanstalk or other services as it makes deployments or rollbacks very easy.